# `react/require-default-props` shows error despite default prop value defined - why?

Tags: typescript, eslint, eslint-plugin-react

This question is about the rule [require-default-props](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/require-default-props.md).

Here's my code:

```
function MyComponent({
  blubb = 'my default',
}: {
  blubb?: string,
}) {
  // blubb is 'my default' by default
};
```

Eslint complains that `MyComponent.defaultProps` is not configured correctly.

In fact I didn't set it up because the default is already part of the function signature. (which works)

Question 1: Why does `eslint-plugin-react` require defaults to be set under defaultProps and not the way I defined it above?

Question 2: Why is this rule even enabled by default? Isn't the purpose of optional parameters TO BE OPTIONAL? What if my default value is simply... `undefined`? Why do I have to define a default value of `undefined` when the default is already `undefined`?

Thank you in advance. <)

Comment: Did you find any solution to this, I'm facing the same issue here?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a rule in eslintrc.js according to the [documentation](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/require-default-props.md#rule-options)

Add the following code to the rules section

```
'react/require-default-props': [2, {
  functions: 'defaultArguments',
}],
```